# Multple Google Maps with Multiple Markers on one page.

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to put 2 google maps with multiple markers with different locations on a page with Google Maps API V3. I have gotten this far:

```
  jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});
function initialize() {
    var map,map2,mapOptions,mapOptions2,markers,markers2,infoWindowContent,infoWindowContent2;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        scrollwheel: false,
        styles:[
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "saturation": -100 }
    ]
  }
],
    };

   var mapOptions2 = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        scrollwheel: false,
        styles:[
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "saturation": -100 }
    ]
  }
],
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google-maps"), mapOptions);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("locations-google"), mapOptions2);
    map.setTilt(45);
    map2.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['TITLE HERE', 1,1],
        ['TITLE HERE', 1,1]
    ];

    var markers2 = [
        ['TITLE HERE', 1,1],
        ['TITLE HERE', 1,1]
    ];




        var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h4>TITLE HERE</h4>' +
        'info here'  +     
           '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h4>TITLE HERE</h4>' +
        'info here' +
        '</div>']
    ]; 

        var infoWindowContent2 = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h4>TITLE HERE</h4>' +
        'info here'  +     
           '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h4>TITLE HERE</h4>' +
        'info here' +
        '</div>']
    ];        

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    var infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker2, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/marker.png"

        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


    for( i = 0; i < markers2.length; i++ ) {
        var position2 = new google.maps.LatLng(markers2[i][1], markers2[i][2]);
        bounds2.extend(position2);
        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position2,
            map: map2,
            title: markers2[i][0],
            icon: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/marker.png"

        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', (function(marker2, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent2[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map2, marker2);
            }
        })(marker2, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds2);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(8);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    }
```

But when i run this, the first map will work fine and displays the correct number of locations etc. But when it comes to the second one it doesn't load and gives me this error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null". I am so so puzzled to why its doing it and i cannot figure it out at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) before trying over-complicated implementations of the maps API.

You have several issues in your code, such as non-declared variables, etc.

One thing that you definitely need to fix is the **mapOptions**:

There are 2 **required** parameters: `center` and `zoom`. Also the `mapTypeId` cannot be declared as you did.

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Try to fix this first and see if it gets any better.

Comment: Although these parameters are defined as required they may be omitted when the fitBounds-method will be called(fitBounds will set both, center and zoom)

Comment: Hey that's right. Adding the center and zoom level actually fixed the error but I didn't realize the fitBounds was called twice on the same map object. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You call both times the `fitBounds`-method of the same Maps-instance: `map`

The 2nd call:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds2);
```

should be

```
map2.fitBounds(bounds2);
```